# Have to set permissions on every startup

Tags: 12.10, permissions

I just installed a fingerprint library called [libfprint](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint). After installing, you have to set the [permissions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fprint#Permissions) up to access the scanner.

I thought that this would be permanent but every time I restart I have to set the permissions again

i.e

```
gpasswd -a USER plugdev
chgrp -R plugdev /dev/bus/usb/
```

Any ideas how to set these permanently ??

Comment: Are you sure you have to execute `gpasswd` again after restart?

Comment: I have just been putting them in every time I start and it solves the problem, maybe I only have to put in chgrp...

Comment: Have you completed the [Login Conf.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fprint#Login_configuration) step?

Comment: Yep sure have...